# spark-solr building jar using maven issue

Tags: maven, hadoop, apache-spark, solr, jar

I am struggling with building jar files using maven for spark-solr. 
Most probably it is due scala version but I am not sure how to deal with that. I have scala 2.10.5 installed with spark 1.6.2
I am running  **mvn clean package -DskipTests -e**

and below is the error I am getting.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-solr: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed. CompileFailed -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile (scala-compile-first) on project spark-solr: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution scala-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.2:compile failed.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Below is pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.lucidworks.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-solr</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>spark-solr</name>
  <description>Tools for reading data from Spark into Solr</description>
  <url>https://github.com/LucidWorks/spark-solr</url>
  <licenses>
    <license>
      <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
      <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
      <distribution>repo</distribution>
      <comments>A business-friendly OSS license</comments>
    </license>
  </licenses>
  <developers>
    <developer>
      <name>Lucidworks</name>
      <organization>Lucidworks</organization>
      <organizationUrl>www.lucidworks.com</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
  </developers>
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:LucidWorks/spark-solr.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:LucidWorks/spark-solr.git</developerConnection>
    <url>https://github.com/LucidWorks/spark-solr</url>
  </scm>
  <distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>ossrh</id>
      <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spark.version>1.6.2</spark.version>
    <solr.version>6.1.0</solr.version>
    <fasterxml.version>2.4.0</fasterxml.version>
    <scala.version>2.10.5</scala.version>
    <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
    <scoverage.plugin.version>1.1.1</scoverage.plugin.version>
    <MaxPermSize>128m</MaxPermSize>
  </properties>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>release</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>attach-javadocs</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>coverage</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
            <configuration>
              <excludes>
              <exclude>com/lucidworks/spark/example/**</exclude>
              <exclude>**/*Test*</exclude>
              </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>default-report</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scoverage.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
              <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <argLine>${argLine} -XX:MaxPermSize=${MaxPermSize}</argLine>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>eclipse-add-source</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test-compile-first</id>
            <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-scaladocs</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>doc-jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>
          <useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
          <javacArgs>
            <javacArg>-source</javacArg>
            <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
            <javacArg>-target</javacArg>
            <javacArg>${java.version}</javacArg>
          </javacArgs>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${java.version}</source>
          <target>${java.version}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- Surefire runs Java tests -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <argLine> -XX:MaxPermSize=${MaxPermSize}</argLine>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- ScalaTest runs Scala tests -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <stderr/>
          <!-- Log to stderr -->
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <!-- Directory/ies for JUnit XML -->
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
          <argLine>-ea -XX:MaxPermSize=${MaxPermSize}</argLine>
          <systemProperties>
            <java.awt.headless>true</java.awt.headless>
            <java.io.tmpdir>${project.build.directory}/tmp</java.io.tmpdir>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
              <shadedClassifierName>shaded</shadedClassifierName>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org.apache.spark:spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.spark:spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.hadoop:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.google.protobuf_spark:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.twitter:chill_${scala.binary.version}</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.twitter:chill-java</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.spark-project.akka:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.spark-project:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.eclipse.jetty:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.scala-lang:scala-library</exclude>
                  <exclude>commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.curator:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.commons:commons-lang3</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.ning:compress-lzf</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java</exclude>
                  <exclude>net.jpountz.lz4:lz4</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.kryo:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>log4j:log4j</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.reflectasm:reflectasm</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.esotericsoftware.minlog:minlog</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.objenesis:objenesis</exclude>
                  <exclude>commons-net:commons-net</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.james:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all</exclude>
                  <exclude>javax.xml.stream:stax-api</exclude>
                  <exclude>javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api</exclude>
                  <exclude>xml-apis:xml-apis</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.ow2.asm:asm</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.codahale.metrics:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>io.dropwizard.metrics:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl</exclude>
                  <exclude>com.sun.jersey:jersey-client</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <relocations>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.apache.http</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.apache.http</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.codehaus.jackson</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.codehaus.jackson</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.fasterxml.jackson</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.fasterxml.jackson</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.objectweb.asm</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.objectweb.asm</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.joda.time</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.joda.time</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.google.guava</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.google.guava</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>com.sun.jersey</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.sun.jersey</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>javax.ws.rs</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.javax.ws.rs</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
                <!-- Commented out because the maven-shade-plugin does not work for Scala classes due to ScalaSig-->
                <!--<relocation>-->
                  <!--<pattern>org.apache.solr</pattern>-->
                  <!--<shadedPattern>shaded.apache.solr</shadedPattern>-->
                <!--</relocation>-->
                <relocation>
                  <pattern>org.apache.commons.cli</pattern>
                  <shadedPattern>shaded.apache.commons.cli</shadedPattern>
                </relocation>
              </relocations>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>attach-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>nexus-staging-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <configuration>
          <serverId>ossrh</serverId>
          <nexusUrl>https://oss.sonatype.org/</nexusUrl>
          <autoReleaseAfterClose>true</autoReleaseAfterClose>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.orbit</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.esotericsoftware.kryo</groupId>
      <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
      <version>2.21</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
      <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-twitter_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
      <version>${solr.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
      <version>${solr.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-test-framework</artifactId>
      <version>${solr.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.restlet.jee</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.servlet</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
      <version>${fasterxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${fasterxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${fasterxml.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
      <classifier>tests</classifier>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
      <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-csv_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- optional dependency of joda-time that is mandatory in Scala -->
      <groupId>org.joda</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-convert</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
      <artifactId>wiremock</artifactId>
      <version>1.56</version>

      <!-- Include everything below here if you have dependency conflicts -->
      <classifier>standalone</classifier>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
          <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
          <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
          <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
          <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>net.sf.jopt-simple</groupId>
          <artifactId>jopt-simple</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: adding pom.xml to your post would help

Comment: And you know your code compiles before trying to create a jar, right?

Comment: @feedev I have edited the question and added pom.xml

Comment: @Vidya this code is part of lucidwork solr package so I guess there should be any compilation issues.